# Mysql sort rows by comparing them

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have table with sport teams standings, there is a column "points" (every won game * 3 + every tied game).

```
------------------------------------------
Name | Played | Won | Lost | Tied | Points
------------------------------------------
  A  |   3    |  2  |  1   |   0  |   6
  B  |   3    |  2  |  1   |   0  |   6
... (other rows not listed)
```

I sort table by points and then by direct matches. **Now let's say "B" has won over the "A", so A should be listed first. How do I do this?**

Here are my tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `games` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hometeam` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `awayteam` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `won` enum('home','away','tie') DEFAULT NULL,
  `home_score` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `away_score` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `teams` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I get my standings table this way:

```
SELECT 
    tt.name
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM games tg WHERE (tt.id = tg.hometeam OR tt.id = tg.awayteam) AND tg.won IS NOT NULL) as `games_played`
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM games tg WHERE (tt.id = tg.hometeam AND tg.won = "home") OR (tt.id = tg.awayteam AND tg.won = "away")) as `games_won`
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM games tg WHERE (tt.id = tg.hometeam AND tg.won = "away") OR (tt.id = tg.awayteam AND tg.won = "home")) as `games_lost`
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM games tg WHERE (tt.id = tg.hometeam OR tt.id = tg.awayteam) AND tg.won = "tied") as `games_tied`
    ,(SELECT `games_won`*3 + `games_tied`) AS `points`
FROM
    teams tt
ORDER BY `points` DESC
```

Comment: How would you sort this case: A won against B, B won versus C, C topped A? I guess there is a fundamental error in your plan

Comment: @Psi could be done based on date, considering the "latest win" to be more important. However in that case, I would also do something different which makes it more easy: Track the timestamp the points changed the LAST Time. Then, if two teams are having an equal amount, the team that is already ranked 1st remains first.

Comment: If sort condition #2 cant decide, sort condition #3 would be used (something like fewer games played, fewer score allowed, etc) :)